# Hiding Script Command Output

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I'm building a shell script to automatically configure a specific computer with the best settings.  I would like to hide all output from this script except for echo output. Is it possible?

Comment: You can end each line in `&> /dev/null` except the echos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start your script with:

```
exec 3>&1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

That will save your original file descriptor for stdout to &3, and then redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null.  Whenever you want to print something, redirect its output to &3, like:

```
echo "This message won't be output"
echo "But this one will" >&3
```

And if you want to hide that detail, you can just define a function that echoes to fd 3:

```
say() {
    echo >&3 "$@"
}

say "This goes to the log"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect stdout to `/dev/null` by adding

`1>/dev/null`

at the end of each line of your script that will produce output.

You can redirect errors the same way by adding

`2>/dev/null`

Most commands also have an option to turn off normal output to the console like `-q` or something like that. Check the manpages of the commands you use.